# for some prime number p, if for the group G, $|G| = p^2$ then either G is abelian or the centre of G = {e}

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Told to use the face that if the quotient group of G and its centre is cyclic, then G is abelian. ie:

$G \over Z(G)$ is cyclic $ \Rightarrow $ G is abelian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, if $|G| = p^2 $ then $G$ is abelian.

Proof: Since $G$ is a $p$-group, $Z(G) \ne \{e\}$ (by the class equation). So we have $|Z(G)| = p$ or $|Z(G)| = p^2$. In the first case, $|G /Z(G)| = p$ so it is cyclic and by your lemma, it is abelian. In the second case $G = Z(G)$ and $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I understand if |G/Z(G)| is prime then it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$ and therefore cyclic but i don't understand how $|G| = p^2$ helps to get there.

Comment: $Z(G)$ is always a normal subgroup of $G$ so if the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is of prime order then it is cyclic. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $Z(G)$ has to divide $p^2$, so $|Z(G)| = 1,p,p^2$. But $Z(G) \ne \{e\}$ so that only leaves $|Z(G)| = p, p^2$. The rest is explained in my answer.